# Telerik JustMock throws exception when trying to mock SPServiceContext

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2010, mocking, justmock

I'm trying to write some unit tests for a Sharepoint 2010 Webpart that uses UserProfile manager.
In order to mock UserProfileManager, I also need to mock SPServiceContext.

When I try to assign my mock variable, like this:

```
_mockServiceContext = Mock.Create<SPServiceContext>();
```

The following exception is thrown:

Type 'Telerik.JustMock.MockException' in assembly 'Telerik.JustMock, Version=2013.1.507.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=721b6c5bc0326b3a' is not marked as serializable.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this issue.

It appears this is a bug in JustMock 2013 Q1 SP2 which has already been fixed. The fix will be included in the upcoming internal build due this month. An internal build is a preview of our upcoming major release - Q2 2013. So please give it a try once it's out and let us know what your feedback is.

I hope this information helps.

Comment: I'm using the version of JustMock available through NuGet. Will the preview release be available there?

Comment: Yes, it will be available on NuGet as well.

Comment: I've had a chance to use the latest version of JustMock, and the same original line of code throws the following exception:

Type is not resolved for member 'Telerik.JustMock.Core.ElevatedMockingException,Telerik.JustMock, Version=2013.2.611.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=721b6c5bc0326b3a'.

Anything else I can try?